# What is the difference between "meat" and "flesh"?

Tags: differences, synonyms

When do we use "meat" and when do we use "flesh"?
I think the difference is very subtle: maybe meat refers to food, and flesh to human or animal bodies, but as English is not my mother tongue, I want to be sure of the specific meanings and usage of both words.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [What is the difference between 'flesh' and 'meat'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65586/), but because that earlier one has no upvoted answers (and has been closed as General Reference) I can't closevote this one as a dup. So I'm closevoting as GR.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The question you quoted doesn't exist anymore. Well done.

Answer (score 12):

The word *meat* originally meant food more generally and only became restricted to food from animals around 1300: the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=meat) gives its current narrower meaning as "flesh used as food".

So if you are not thinking about eating it, literally or metaphorically, you should not use *meat*.  You can use *flesh* whether or not you you might consider eating it.

Comment: Like *nut meat*.